# Let the user store value into a string array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having some trouble letting a user save his value into an array, here's the code that I tried with:
I want to be able to store up to 4 objects, and then reset them with null, if that is possible.

```
string [] array = new string[4];
array[i] += Console.ReadLine(); //and now it says: Cannot implicitly convert
 type 'string' to 'int'. I also want to reset the value with this code:

array[i] = null;
```

I'm new to arrays and it's really hard. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does `i` come from? Presumably you want `=` instead of `+=` but the error you've shown looks more likely to do with `i`

Comment: I thought 'i' stood for index, so I used that to store strings into my array @Sayse

Comment: `i` refers to a variable name that is often used to denote an index, but that depends on how you define it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `i` variable that has a type `string` instead of `int`. You need to use integer values for your indexer in array.

Also there is no reason to use `+=` operator. Just assign your value to the array element by using `=`.

```
var index = int.Parse(i); // the better way is to use TryParse to check your i string contains integer value
array[index] = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like you are trying to index the array using a name.  If so, I would use a `Dictionary` instead:

```
var key = "MyValueKey";  //I presume this is currently your "i" value
var dict = new Dictionary<String, String>();
var userVal = Console.ReadLine();
if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(userVal))
    userVal = null;
if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
    dict[key] = userVal;
else
    dict.Add(key, userVal);
```